# Head is getting reversed in a linked list for a palindrome validation algo

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write an algorithm that checks if an input LinkedList is a palindrome or not. My algorithm is as follows:

1. Set a dummy node to point to the head of the input linkedList
2. Use a handler to store the reversed linkedlist
3. Run a loop to compare the values from front and back

My error: I know that the algorithm is wrong, because the output that I get seems to say that my original head is pointing in the wrong direction. I cannot figure out why, since I have used handler nodes while reversing as well.

The code is as follows:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        if(head==null) return true;
        ListNode dummy = head;
        ListNode MatchList = null;
        MatchList=reverseList(head);               
        while(dummy!=null)
        {
            if(dummy.val!=MatchList.val)
            {return false;}
            MatchList=MatchList.next;
            dummy=dummy.next;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        ListNode dummy, newHead;
        newHead=head;
        ListNode another=newHead;
        ListNode prev=null;
        while(another!=null)
        {
            dummy=another.next;
            another.next=prev;
            prev=another;
            another=dummy;
        }
        return prev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your attempt is that when you reverse the list, it happens to *that* list. Yet your code deals with it as if it is a second list, independent from the first list. But because it is not, the `head` node has become the tail, and so after `reverseList` has been called, `head.next` (i.e. `dummy.next`) is going to be `null`.

A simple idea would be to change `reverseList` so that it creates a new list, calling the `ListNode` constructor for each node it encounters, but then linking them in the opposite direction.

This is however not an ideal solution, as it needs O(n) auxiliary space.

There is the following "trick" you can apply:

- Find the middle node of the list (or if the size is even, the first one of the second half).
- Reverse the list that starts at that node, i.e. reverse the second half of the list
- Now you can walk in both halves and compare the values in tandem.

To make that work, here is  a function you could use:

```
public ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
    ListNode fast = head;
    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        head = head.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

And now you can do:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null) return true;
    ListNode mid = middleNode(head);
    ListNode tail = reverseList(mid);
    while (tail != null) {
        if (head.val != tail.val) return false;
        tail = tail.next;
        head = head.next;
    }
    return true;
}
```